# case types boolean and double precision cannot be matched in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Query : if b is credit (i.e 0 or greater than 0), then the values should be a. Otherwise (a+b), and negative values should be zero.

My query condition is

```
Case when(b>=0) Then (a) Else (SUM(a+b)>0 End as Difference
```

But I'm getting this error

```
Error : CASE Types boolean and double precision cannot be matched
```

It would be a great pleasure if someone assist for the query solution. I'm using Postgres as database.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your expression; the number of opening and closing parentheses doesn't match.

But `a` is a number, while `a + b > 0` is a boolean value (“true” or “false”), so PostgreSQL complains that it cannot determine what the type of your case expression should be.

According to your description, I would use

```
CASE WHEN b >= 0
     THEN a
     ELSE greatest(a + b, 0)
END
```

Comment: Thank You Sir for your quick response.  I'll check and let you know..